# Taylor diagram in python by using skill_metrics

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried to use skill_metris to create taylor diagram. But I am getting error saying that

```
module 'matplotlib.colors' has no attribute 'to_rgb'
```

example code:

```
import skill_metrics as sm
sm.taylor_diagram(0.22,0.52,0.32)
```

Comment: Could you tell us which version of skill_metrics and matplotlib are you using? You can check it with following code: 

`python
import matplotlib
import skill_metrics
matplotlib.__version__
'2.1.0'
skill_metrics.__version__
'1.1.4'
`

Comment: so skill_metrics is '1.1.4' and matplotlib is '1.5.1'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer can be find on github project FAQ
https://github.com/PeterRochford/SkillMetrics/wiki/FAQ
From site:

> A3. This problem occurs when using an earlier version of matplotlib
>   than 2.0.0. The latter is distributed with Python 3.6 but standard
>   distributions of Python 2.7 are usually distributed with earlier
>   versions of matplotlib (e.g. 1.3.1 and 1.5.0). To check what version
>   of matplotlib you are using execute the following statements at the
>   Python command line (or within a script):

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.__version__
```

I order to get newer matplotlib version you can use following pip command. `pip install -U matplotlib`.

Comment: Thank you Alex for your Help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by installing the following modules on google colab:

```
! pip install XlsxWriter
! pip install SkillMetrics
```